# Springboot - Login form after starting application

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using IntelliJ and I am trying to run following example:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_bootstrapping.htm

After application starts, when I go to `localhost:8080` it is redirected to
`localhost:8080/login` and form with `"Login with Username and Password"`

I have no Tomcat directory in `TOMCAT_HOME` (in all manuals to solve this I should have file `tomcat-users.xml` in mentioned directory)

So how to find out the username and password for this?

Comment: did you add `spring-security` in your dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have `spring-boot-starter-security` on your classpath and thats why Spring security is automatically get configured. Verify that you have this following dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can also notice that in the application console you have the following log when application starts

`Using default security password: ce6c3d39-8f20-4a41-8e01-803166bb99b6`

That means Spring Security has automatically added this as your password where the user id is `user`

If you want to change this password to something else, you can configure in *application.properties* to anything as

`security.user.password=password`

For more details follow this [Spring Security References](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I started an application, searched localhost://8080.
I diagnosed my error by removing this dependency in my POM.XML file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```